# How to create a "Ghost Table" in SQL Server based off of other tables?

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a "ghost" table in SQL Server, which doesn't actually exist but is a result set of a SQL Query.  Pseudo code is below:

```
SELECT genTbl_col1, genTblcol2 
FROM genTbl;
```

However, "genTbl" is actually:

```
SELECT table1.col AS genTbl_col1, 
    table2.col AS genTbl_col2
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (...)
```

In other words, I need that every time a query is run on the server trying to select from "genTbl", it simply creates a result set from the query and treats it like a real table.

The situation is that I have a software that runs queries on a database.  I need to modify it, but I cannot change the software itself, so I need to trick it into thinking it can actually query "genTbl", when it actually doesn't exist but is simply a query of other tables.

To clarify, the query would have to be a sort of procedure, available by default in the database (i.e. every time there is a query for "genTbl").

Comment: I think you are talking about temp tables, easiest way is: SELECT table1.col AS genTbl_col1, 
    table2.col AS genTbl_col2 INTO #GHOST_TABLE
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (...)

Comment: I think you are looking for a [`view`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql)

Comment: Look into `Views`

Comment: Why not create a view with that query?

Comment: because he needs a `GHOST TABLE` that does not actually exist....

Comment: @long he needs to query from `genTbl` as if it *did* exist. So he needs to create a `view` named `genTbl` with the appropriate source data and column names

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, he could query from temp table within the session, and it will be dropped when session ends, close to `GHOST` xD

Comment: Except his queries are supposed to be  `select... from genTbl` and *not* `insert...into #tmptbl; select.. from #tmptbl`

Comment: I like the term Ghost Table better than View, I think this is a good (albeit very basic) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use #TMP

```
SELECT genTbl_col1, genTblcol2 
INTO #TMP FROM genTbl;
```

It exists only in current session. You can also use ##TMP for all sessions.